# Sentencia NOT IN hace que la consulta tarde en ejecutarse ocasionando error

Tags: sql-server, sql

Al ejecutar en la base de datos tarda aproximadamente 40-50 segundos, si quito NOT IN tarda 1 o 2 segundos pero para los registros que quiero obtener necesito usar el NOT IN.

Dejo la consulta:

```
SELECT d.estado, 
       c.cec          AS cec, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), c.cec) + ' | ' 
       + c.cec_descri AS adscripcion, 
       b.modulo, 
       b.modulotitulo, 
       b.tema, 
       b.tematitulo, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN a.calificacion = 'ap' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)       AS aprobados, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN a.calificacion = 'na' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)       AS noAprobados 
FROM   (SELECT a1.cecvoluntario, 
               a1.clavevoluntario, 
               a1.modulo, 
               a1.tema, 
               Max(a1.calificacion)           AS maxcalificacion, 
               'ap'                           AS calificacion, 
               a1.clavevoluntario 
               + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.modulo) 
               + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.tema) AS pk 
        FROM   bdvoluntarios.dbo.capacitacionevaluaciones AS a1 
        WHERE  a1.calificacion >= 6 
               AND CONVERT(DATE, a1.fechacaptura) BETWEEN 
                   '2020/01/01' AND '2020/03/31' 
        GROUP  BY a1.cecvoluntario, 
                  a1.clavevoluntario, 
                  a1.modulo, 
                  a1.tema 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT a1.cecvoluntario, 
               a1.clavevoluntario, 
               a1.modulo, 
               a1.tema, 
               Max(a1.calificacion)           AS maxcalificacion, 
               'na'                           AS calificacion, 
               a1.clavevoluntario 
               + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.modulo) 
               + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.tema) AS pk 
        FROM   bdvoluntarios.dbo.capacitacionevaluaciones AS a1 
        WHERE  a1.calificacion <= 5 
               AND CONVERT(DATE, a1.fechacaptura) BETWEEN 
                   '2020/01/01' AND '2020/03/31' 
               AND a1.clavevoluntario 
                   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.modulo) 
                   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.tema) NOT IN (SELECT 
                   a1.clavevoluntario 
                   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.modulo) 
                   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.tema) 
                                                          FROM 
                       bdvoluntarios.dbo.capacitacionevaluaciones AS a1 
                                                          WHERE 
                   a1.calificacion >= 6) 
        GROUP  BY a1.cecvoluntario, 
                  a1.clavevoluntario, 
                  a1.modulo, 
                  a1.tema) AS a, 
       bdvoluntarios.dbo.capacitaciontemas AS b, 
       cec AS c, 
       bdvoluntarios.dbo.catalogoregional AS d 
WHERE  a.cecvoluntario = c.cec 
       AND a.cecvoluntario = d.cec 
       AND a.modulo = b.modulo 
       AND a.tema = b.tema 
GROUP  BY d.estado, 
          c.cec_descri, 
          b.modulo, 
          b.modulotitulo, 
          b.tema, 
          b.tematitulo, 
          c.cec 
ORDER  BY d.estado, 
          c.cec, 
          b.modulo, 
          b.tema;
```

Comment: Dale formato a tu código es un mínimo de etiqueta que hay que seguir al preguntar en internet.

Comment: Tuve un buffer overflow mental tratando de digerir la sentencia ...

Comment: ¡Esa consulta es ilegible para un humano!

Comment: Archer puedes usar una herramienta para formatear el SQL. No edites la pregunta eliminando el contenido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar la subconsulta del NOT IN al nivel superior y unirla con un left join, despues aceptar solo aquellos que no se unan.  Pienso que puede funcionar.

```
SELECT
   d.estado,
   c.cec AS cec,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), c.cec) + ' | ' + c.cec_descri AS adscripcion,
   b.modulo,
   b.moduloTitulo,
   b.tema,
   b.temaTitulo,
   SUM(
   CASE
      WHEN
         a.calificacion = 'ap' 
      THEN
         1 
      ELSE
         0 
   END
) AS aprobados, SUM(
   CASE
      WHEN
         a.calificacion = 'na' 
      THEN
         1 
      ELSE
         0 
   END
) AS noAprobados 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         a1.cecVoluntario,
         a1.claveVoluntario,
         a1.modulo,
         a1.tema,
         Max(a1.calificacion) AS maxcalificacion,
         'ap' AS calificacion,
         a1.claveVoluntario + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.modulo) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.tema) AS pk 
      FROM
         BdVoluntarios.dbo.capacitacionEvaluaciones AS a1 
      WHERE
         a1.calificacion >= 6 
         AND CONVERT(DATE, a1.fechaCaptura) BETWEEN '2020/01/01' AND '2020/03/31' 
      GROUP BY
         a1.cecVoluntario,
         a1.claveVoluntario,
         a1.modulo,
         a1.tema 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
         a1.cecVoluntario,
         a1.claveVoluntario,
         a1.modulo,
         a1.tema,
         Max(a1.calificacion) AS maxcalificacion,
         'na' AS calificacion,
         a1.claveVoluntario + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.modulo) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.tema) AS pk 
      FROM
         BdVoluntarios.dbo.capacitacionEvaluaciones AS a1 
         LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
               a1.claveVoluntario + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.modulo) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.tema) clave
            FROM
               BdVoluntarios.dbo.capacitacionEvaluaciones AS a1 
            WHERE
               a1.calificacion >= 6
         ) a1_a ON a1.claveVoluntario + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.modulo) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a1.tema = a1_a.clave
      WHERE
         a1.calificacion <= 5 
         AND CONVERT(DATE, a1.fechaCaptura) BETWEEN '2020/01/01' AND '2020/03/31' 
         AND a1_a.clave is null
      GROUP BY
         a1.cecVoluntario,
         a1.claveVoluntario,
         a1.modulo,
         a1.tema
   )
   AS a,
   BdVoluntarios.dbo.capacitacionTemas AS b,
   cec AS c,
   BdVoluntarios.dbo.catalogoRegional AS d 
WHERE
   a.cecVoluntario = c.cec 
   AND a.cecVoluntario = d.cec 
   AND a.modulo = b.modulo 
   AND a.tema = b.tema 
GROUP BY
   d.estado,
   c.cec_descri,
   b.modulo,
   b.moduloTitulo,
   b.tema,
   b.temaTitulo,
   c.cec 
ORDER BY
   d.estado,
   c.cec,
   b.modulo,
   b.tema;
```

Comment: Gracias EdgardoO! si me funciono